# MS SQL trigger remove all before

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Need some help...

I have a column whereby the data is shown as -

```
USEREMAIL:-USERNAME   
e.g. 
John.smith@test.com:-JSmit                         
janet.smit@test.co.uk:-JanSmit                       
peter.parker@test.ca:-PPark
```

I need a trigger that will automatically remove everything apart from the username when a new entry is added.

So the above examples would just become

```
JSmit
JanSmit
PPark
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should show what you have try so far.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the syntax to create the described trigger:

Test table:

```
CREATE TABLE xx(UserName varchar(100))
```

You will have to expand the trigger to contain all columns.

Trigger syntax:

```
CREATE TRIGGER xx_trggr
ON  xx
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO xx (UserName)
    SELECT stuff(UserName, 1, charindex(':-', UserName) + 1, '')
    FROM inserted
END 
GO
```

Inserting data:

```
INSERT xx(UserName)
values
('John.smith@test.com:-JSmit'),
('janet.smit@test.co.uk:-JanSmit'),
('peter.parker@test.ca:-PPark')
```

Testing input:

```
SELECT UserName FROM xx
```

Result:

```
UserName
JSmit
JanSmit
PPark
```

You could make an AFTER trigger instead, but that would require a unique key

Using this table instead:

```
CREATE TABLE xx(id int identity(1,1), UserName varchar(100))
```

And this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER xx_trggr
ON  xx
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE xx
    SET [UserName] = stuff(xx.UserName, 1, charindex(':-', xx.UserName) + 1, '')
    FROM inserted JOIN xx On inserted.id = xx.id
END
```

Same result as the other trigger.

Comment: Look at the comments on the other answers! The email adress can contain - sign.

Comment: @GaborRajczi ok, thanks, compensated for that looking for *:-* instead

Answer (score 0):

This will give you username from column

```
SET columnName= select SUBSTRING( columnName, CHARINDEX('-',columnName)+1 , LEN(columnName))
```

Use it in trigger

EDIT 1: (If you are worried your email can contain `-`)

```
 SET columnName= select SUBSTRING( columnName, CHARINDEX(':-',columnName)+2 , LEN(columnName))
```

Comment: Check Edit, email can't possibly contain `:-`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `AFTER INSERT` trigger on your table and in your trigger body use something like below to strip down the email part

```
select right('John.smith@test.com:-JSmit',(LEN('John.smith@test.com:-JSmit') - CHARINDEX('-','John.smith@test.com:-JSmit')))
```

Comment: You should change `CHARINDEX('-'` to `CHARINDEX(':-'` See my comment for @Pravin Deshmukh